# НЕ пойму как получить данные с ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $block = $('.js-toBtc'),
            price = $block.text(),
            url = 'https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=' + price;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            cache       : false,
            dataType    : 'jsonp',
            jsonp       : 'c',
            success: function(html) {
                console.log(html);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Собственно это весь запрос, но Я не могу понять почему мне не поступают данные данные (в консоли это видно что ответ на запрос поступил и верный а success не проходит), Я не могу их вывести.

Вопрос почему не срабатывает success и как получить данные которые были загружены.

Как вывести в данные которые загружает ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте такой обработчик

```
complete: function(xhr, status) { console.log(status, xhr); }
```

в опции вызова `$.ajax()` и посмотрите какой статус ответа, возможно `parsererror`.

Comment: вывел parsererror и объект

Comment: Я поняла... Но теперь есть другая проблема "XMLHttpRequest cannot load" -  её можно как то избежать, не подключая прокси?

Comment: $.ajax ожидает в ответ данные в формате JSON, а получает обычным текстом...

Comment: @GrayHoax это Я уже поняла изменила на верный формат выскочило "XMLHttpRequest cannot load" как от него избавиться не используя прокси

Comment: Никак :) это же ошибка парсинга ответа

Comment: Сервер blockchain.info не пропускает кросс-доменные запросы. Либо со своего сервера получать данные, либо использовать что-то вроде [easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM). Можно ещё написать админам сервиса, разьяснить, что их сервис мог быть куда более полезней, если они разрешат XDM запросы - от них требуется только один заголовок прописать.

Answer (score -1):

А почему POST запрос? Попробуй GET. Это во первых.

Во вторых сервер присылает данные в неправильном формате. При jsonp запросе в урле указывается параметр callback (в твоем случае с) - это имя функции, которая вызовется на клиенте, а сервер должен завернуть свои данные в вызов этой функции, вот так:

```
callbackName(0.04247908)
```

Я же вижу просто цифры:

https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=10&c=jQuery21302944839936681092_1428673006899&_=1428673006900

Comment: Если сервис не выставляет cors заголовки и не поддерживает jsonp, то напрямую из браузера не получится сделать запрос, придется его проксировать через свой сервер (на том же домене, где находится показывающая страница).